# Hypergeometric function limit to Cosh[] or Sin[]

Tags: special-functions

I have this hypergeometric function I woluld like to see in which condition goes to Cosh[] o Sin[]

```
Sqrt[1/a] x Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/b, 1 + 1/b, -(f x^b)/a]
```

thanks
[image]

Comment: do you mean `Sqrt@(1/a) x Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/b, 1 + 1/b, -(f x^b)/a]` ?

Comment: Yes, dude I mean this

Comment: I know that hypergeometrics reduce to ordinary elementary functions for appropriate values of their arguments, but is there any reason to believe that it will go to these particular ones? Do you have any source or can you make a justification?

Comment: look this for example

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. I know that the ${}_2F_{1}$ will simplify to logs, etc etc in special limits. Which is what I said previously and what you are showing. I am asking the following: is there a concrete reason to believe it will reduce to `Cosh[whatever]` or are we looking to figure out if it does? That's my question

Comment: I want to see put some conditions on it to goes Cosh

Answer (score 6):

As a start point, try

```
Table[{a, b, f, Sqrt@(1/a) x Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/b, 1 + 1/b, -(f x^b)/a]}, {a,1, 3, 1/2}, {b, 1, 3, 1/2}, {f, 1, 3, 1/2}]
```

which  has about 50 elementary outputs. Play with it on your own.